# Pandas Drop Rows when a String is Matched to a Longer String in a Column in an Exact Match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop rows in a pandas DataFrame if a substring in a column exactly matches a string in a list. At the moment I can only get it working for partial matches.

```
# list of strings to drop in an exact match
drop_list = ["sock", "shirt"]

# initialize data of lists.
data = {'keyword': ['adidas socks', 'adidas sock', 'adidas shoes', "sock"]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[~df['keyword'].str.contains("|".join(drop_list))]
```

Current Output:

```
        keyword
2  adidas shoes
```

Desired Output:

```
        keyword
0  adidas socks
1  adidas shoes
```

Comment: whoops, edited. Good catch!

Comment: Edited again, I'm not very good at this tonight! Sorry about that. Desired output should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set from `drop_list` and use `set.isdisjoint` on the split words in each row to evaluate if the exact match appears.

```
drop_set = set(drop_list)
msk = df['keyword'].apply(lambda x: drop_set.isdisjoint(x.split()))
df = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
        keyword
0  adidas socks
2  adidas shoes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working.
The only thing I noticed is that the index is not "updated"

To achieve that we could reset the index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
#or
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

I used the sample code you provided but my output looks different than yours but so does the input. 
Honestly, I don't understand why that last empty string of data is not showing up on your output. 
Input:

```
        keyword
0   adidas sock
1  adidas socks
2  adidas shoes
3          sock
4
```

Output:

```
        keyword
0  adidas shoes
1
```

Comment: Apologies, think I'm tired tonight. I've edited the desired output again. Should be right now.